# Building Xinu for BeagleBone Black

Tags: embedded-linux, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, xinu

I am trying to run Xinu on BeagleBoneBlack. I downloaded the file from the xinu website for the ARM BeagleBoneBlack one. Now, in the compile directory, when I run "make" it says ../cross_compiler/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld not found. I don't know why as this file exists. I also tried executing "../cross_compiler/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld" file from the terminal and it also says that it is not found. I don't know why. I changed the permissions to chmod ugo+rwx but it doesn't fix the problem. Can you help?

I tried changing the permissions but that did nothing.

Comment: Simply reporting just the command and resulting error message with no other context is not helpful. What is your shell environment? Why isn't the cross-toolchain in the PATH? Did you have to configure the project before the make? BTW you're probably using the wrong compiler/toolchain. IIRC the BBB has hardware floating point.